# Ansible: How check when: db is present in role variable?

Tags: ansible

So I am trying to understand how to pass role variables in playbooks and I stumbled upon the syntax a bit. I can´t figure out how tell ansible to only create a mysql DB if it does not exist. It is specifically passing it as a role variable that I find challenging. Can it be passed a state=present?

Here is my code:

```
---
- name: Install MySQL
  host: development
  roles:
   - {role: mysql, mysql_db: [{name: benz}], when: ????,
        mysql_users: [{name: ben3, pass: foobar, priv: "*.*:ALL"}], when: ???}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `roles` is the best way to approach the problem because you can't register variables before a role statement gets evaluated. From the documentation you can only use `ansible facts` that actually get evaluated before your playbook executes. Another comment, the `when` keyword is meant to be used only once in the `role` statement:

```
---
- name: Install MySQL
  host: development
  roles:
   - {role: mysql,
      mysql_db: [{name: benz}],
      mysql_users: [{name: ben3, pass: foobar, priv: "*.*:ALL"}],
      when: "some_ansible_fact == 'Whatever'"}
```

You are probably better off putting your checks in playbook tasks if you need to check whether a mysql database exists or not. you can use the `register` keyword to see if a database exists:

```
---
- name: Install Mysql
  hosts: all
  user: myrootuser
  sudo: True
  tags: mytag

  vars:
      mysql_users: [{name: ben3, pass: foobar, priv: "*.*:ALL"}]
      mysql_db: mydatabasename

  tasks:

    - name: Install the mysql package
      apt: pkg=mysql-server state=present

    - name: Find out the master log file name and position
      command: >
        /usr/bin/mysql -umysql_user -pmysql_password
        -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
      register: databases

    - name: Create users if they don't exist
      command: >
        # or run whatever you need to run here to create users
        /usr/bin/mysql -umysql_user -pmysql_password
        -e "CREATE USER {{ mysql_users[0]['name'] }};"
      when: databases.stdout.find('{{ mysql_db }}') != -1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Again Rico. I thought about going this route. But the role variables I found in some of the most popular playbooks on Ansible Galaxy confused me. So most (all?) role variables can past as normal vars?

Comment: @StenW yeah they are regular variables.  But keep in mind that roles are evaluated before variables AFAIK.